# Better and shorter solution of PHP code (wordpress, woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wrote PHP code(I am trying to display woocommerce notice - free shipping for $40 & under only once on shop page and once on cart page, but also in cart should not be more than 40$), the code works, but i am not sure that it is the best way to do it:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$shop_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") ."://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/shop/";

$cart_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") ."://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/cart/";

$first_time_shop = false;

if ((!isset($_COOKIE["mynoticeshop"]))&&($actual_link == $shop_link))
{
    $first_time_shop = true;<br>
    setcookie("mynoticeshop", "mynoticesaleshop", time() + 600, $shop_link);
}
if ($first_time_shop) {
   function sp_custom_notice() {
        $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
        $free_shipping_threshold = 40;
        if ($subtotal < $free_shipping_threshold) {
        wc_add_notice( 'free shipping for $40 & under', 'notice' );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_init', 'sp_custom_notice' );
}

$first_time_cart = false;
if ((!isset($_COOKIE["mynoticecart"]))&&($actual_link == $cart_link)) {
    $first_time_cart = true;
    setcookie("mynoticecart", "mynoticesalecart", time() + 600, $cart_link);
}
if ($first_time_cart) {
   function sp_custom_notice() {
        $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
        $free_shipping_threshold = 40;
        if ($subtotal < $free_shipping_threshold) {
        wc_add_notice( ' free shipping for $40 & under', 'notice' );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_init', 'sp_custom_notice' );
}
```

I am new to Programming and I am interested if there is a better and shorter solution of this code?

--------------UPDATE-------------

```
$actual_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
const FREE_SHIPPING_CONSTANT = 40;
function sp_custom_notice(){
        $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
        if ($subtotal < FREE_SHIPPING_CONSTANT) {
        wc_add_notice( 'free shipping for $40 & under', 'notice' );
    }
};
$first_time_shop = false;
$first_time_cart = false;
if ((!isset($_COOKIE["mynoticeshop"]))&&($actual_link == '/shop/')) {
    $first_time_shop = true;
    setcookie("mynoticeshop", "mynoticesaleshop", time() + 600);
}
if ((!isset($_COOKIE["mynoticecart"]))&&($actual_link == '/cart/')) {
    $first_time_cart = true;
    setcookie("mynoticecart", "mynoticesalecart", time() + 600);
}
if (($first_time_shop)||($first_time_cart)){
    sp_custom_notice();
    add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'sp_custom_notice' );
}
```

Comment: To start with try to use `namespacing`. If you use PHPStorm for example, it is by far more easier to read and to jump to a function. Remember a function need to do just one thing.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Maybe, as far as your code works, this should be better place for your question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: thank you BenRoob and Ronnie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done for a first attempt! However, you're right - you can be doing things better!

Firstly, you don't need the 3 `$*_link` variables as WooCommerce has 2 conditionals - `is_shop()` and `is_cart()` to check if you're on a shop page or a cart page. Also, the `, $shop_link` & `, $cart_link` in the `setcookie`s aren't required, so you can safely get rid of them.

Secondly, you don't need to define the function `sp_custom_notice()` twice and you don't want to define it in an if statement - just the once, outside of the if, will do. Nor should you `add_action()` twice.

Finally, place your cookie & page checks inside of the function.

Personally I believe that the best way to learn is by doing, so I'm not going to show you the corrected code, but if you follow the above advice you should be able to work it out for yourself - to get that far you obviously have a head for it!

To give you a head start though, your entire code block should start with

```
function sp_custom_notice() {
```

and end with

```
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_init', 'sp_custom_notice' );
```

with everything contained within the function.

Hope that helps. Feel free to update your question with your new code if you get stuck and I'll be happy help out.

Comment: thanks for help.. I improved the code :) I updated it, but I still don't know how to put it all into function :(

Comment: also is_shop() and is_cart()  did not work.. I found a solution here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304995/is-shop-doesnt-work-for-woocommerce   .. but i think it is more complicated. @PeterHvD

Comment: I think that `woocommerce_init` is too early in the page setup, so if you attach to the `wp_loaded` action instead that should work. By the way, `woocommerce_init` is an action, not a filter, so you should be using `add_action` anyway.

Comment: Thank you :) you helped me so much :) is there a way to show this notice after 600 seconds, but without reloading the website? @Peter HvD

Comment: You're welcome. I can't see any way of doing that using the `wc_add_notice()` function. Of course, there's nothing to stop you from writing your own notifier function!